# Did Princess Diana ever talk about her alleged Armenian descent?

Tags: royalty, armenia

The Englishwoman Princess Diana (1961-97), born Diana Spencer, was the fourth-greats granddaughter - through a line of matrilineal descent in every step - of Eliza Kewark. Kewark lived in Bombay, India, and is said to have been Armenian, the daughter of Hakob Kevorkian.

Is there any record of Princess Diana having made reference to the fact, likelihood, or possibility of her having Armenian ancestry?

(Note: this question is not about the issue of whether Kewark actually was of Armenian descent. I am aware that some are skeptical about that notion.)

Comment: There is no entry in the index of *Andrew Morton
Diana: Her True Story--in Her Own Words* which would indicate any discussion of the topic there.

Answer (score 2):

I note that Princess Diana did have a much more distant descent from Armenians, whether Eliza Kewark was armenian or not.

I have a copy of *Royal Highness: Ancestry of the Royal Child*, Sir Iain Moncreiffe, 1982, about the ancestry of the as yet unborn child who turned out to be William Prince of Wales.

I suspect that the parents of Prince William might have had a copy of the book about heir son's ancestry, and thus theirs.  So it is perfectly possibly that Princess Diana did know what it said about her remote Armenian ancestry, though I don't know whether she ever considered that more important or interesting than her ancestors of many other different ethnic groups.

Table 9 on pages 48-49 "The Ancient World" traces a rather speculative line of descent from Vologaeses V, Parthian King of Kings from 191 to 208 AD, and his son Chosroes King of Armenia 191-216 AD, down to James of Lusignan, King of Cyprus 1382-1398 and titular king of Jerusalem and Armenia. and says to see table 14.

Table 14 on page 61-62 traces descent from the kings of Jerusalem starting with Baldwin II (r. 1118-1131) through James (d.1398) mentioned above, and through Charlotte de la Tremoille, a French noblewoman who marred James, 7th Earl of Derby (d.1651) and brought that line of descent into the British nobility, and down to Diana Princess of Wales.

But the more remote Armenian ancestors of Princess Diana in this lineage are uncertain.

The royal genealogy site *Medieval Lands* page [https://fmg.ac/Projects/MedLands/CYPRUS.htm#HuguesIVB](https://1:00%20PM)

Shows that King Jacques/James I of Cyprus (d.1398) was the son of King Hugh IV and Alix of Ibelin.

This page  https://fmg.ac/Projects/MedLands/CYPRUS.htm#AliceIbelinM1HuguesIVCyprusM2

shows that Alix was the daugtter of Guy of Ibelin (d. 1308) who was the son of of Balin of Ibelin and Alix of Lampron.

Alix of Lampron was Armenian, a daughter of Hetum IV, Lord of Lampron in Little Armenia.

https://fmg.ac/Projects/MedLands/ARMENIA.htm#Alicediedafter1312

Hetum IV was a son of Konstandin (Constantine) Lord of Lampron, son of Hetum III (d.1 218), son of Oshin II (d. 1143), son of Oshin I (d.1110) lord of Lampron, and his wife, a daughter of Abul Gharib Artsruni governor or Taursus.

https://fmg.ac/Projects/MedLands/ARMENIA.htm#HethumIILapmrondied1143A

And according to Moncreiffe and his sources, Abul Gharib Artsruni was descended from the Armenian kings of Vaspurakan.

The Medieval Lands page on the kings of Vaspurakan lists what seems to be the same Abul Gharib  as son of Hasan and grandson of Gagik/Khachi'k, killed 1042, but doesn't give their relationship to other members of the Artsruni dynasty and to the kings of Vaspurakan.

https://fmg.ac/Projects/MedLands/ARMENIA.htm#_Toc359675589

The genealogis.org website has a ancestor chart tracing the ancestry of Hetum II of Lampron's maternal ancestry back to the kings of Vaspurakan.

https://www.genealogics.org/pedigree.php?personID=I00139831&tree=LEO&parentset=0&display=standard&generations=8

And the next ancestral chart traces their ancestry as far as Ashot the Carniverous, Prince of Armenia (D. 826) but no farther.

https://www.genealogics.org/pedigree.php?personID=I00297824&tree=LEO&parentset=0&display=standard&generations=8

So a bit of research is necessary to decide on the truth or otherwise of the splendid Armenian ancestry of Princess Diana in  *Royal Highness: Ancestry of the Royal Child*, But she is descended from several generations of medieval Armenian lords in little Armenia.

And here is a link to Princess Diana's ancestry chart showing Eliza kewark Kevorkian and her father Habib Kevorkian.

https://www.genealogics.org/pedigree.php?personID=I00000174&tree=LEO&parentset=0&display=standard&generations=8

And Eliza Kewark Kevorkian's page gives only one source.

> [S00168] ~The ancestry of Lady Diana Spencer, Genealogists' Magazine, June 1981 , Williamson, David.
> 394